# VERR_SUPLIB_WRITE_NON_SYS_GROUP?

Tags: virtualbox

Im on a Intel Mac and Ive installed VirtualBox so that I can try some Linux programs. I first installed Ubuntu 12.04, and that was easy as pie! Then, I got greedy and installed Pinguy 12.04 (shell).

Since I did that, I now cannot open either Ubuntu or Pinguy, and I keep getting these error messages.

I can use Terminal, but I dont even know what root is or chmod, etc., so im scared to try it. I am the only user of the computer, but when I bought it, last year, I somehow made a user (my self), but I know how to GetInfo and change permissions, but now I keep getting the message above.

I did check and /user/xxxx/Library/VirtualBox is there, with some files. However, when I create my distros in Virtual Box, a new folder is automatically created and placed at /users/xxxx/VirtualBox VMs  meaning that it isn't putting that folder inside the Library folder.

Im so excited about trying out Linux, but now this VirtualBox is driving me nuts, and I have uninstalled and reinstalled it a couple times, at least.

Here is the log error, in part: "VERR_SUPLIB_WRITE_NON_SYS_GROUP szErr="The group is not a system group and it has write access to '/Applications/VirtualBox.app'"

I dont understand, since I am the owner, shouldn't i HAVE write access?

Appreciate the help from all!

Comment: Might be a better fit on Ask different or Superuser.  The permissions issue/error on an .app file is a problem on the host side, not the guest side and it relates to an application/software problem.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't really explain well what your problem is, but by reading some stuff about your error, it appears that your virtual machine isn't booting up.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=43487
< According to that webpage, somebody solved a similar problem on their system by running `chmod g-w /opt`.

Though in your situation, it looks like you'd want to run `chmod g-w /Applications`.

(or `sudo chmod g-w /Applications`)